# How to have popup or prompt validation password before run a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

Im looking for a way to have a validation password as prompt or popup before running a function.
example: after clicking a button and run a function a popup should comes up and ask to write YESRUNFUNCTION  then click ok and the function will be run its a way of validation.

here is the code Im working with js confirmation

```js
  generate() {
    if(confirm("WARNING! you are about to generate a new Lot #. YOU CAN'T UNDO IT")) {
    const sku = this.myControl.value;
    if (sku) {
      this.lotService.getCurrentLotNumber(sku).subscribe(result => {
        let lotNumber = 'MY';
        
        const dt = new Date();
        this.date = dt;
        const year_time = dt.getFullYear();

        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMonth();
         
         if (n < 10 ) {
          this.foo = n+1;
        }
        if ( n === 9 ) {           
             this.foo= 'O';
        }
        if ( n === 10 ) {           
          this.foo= 'N';
     }
     if ( n === 11 ) {           
      this.foo= 'D';
 }

 if (year_time === 2018 ) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'R'+ this.foo;
}
if (year_time === 2019) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'S'+ this.foo;
}
if (year_time === 2020) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'T'+ this.foo;
}

if (year_time === 2021) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'U'+ this.foo;
}

if (year_time === 2022) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'V'+ this.foo;
}
if (year_time === 2023) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'W'+ this.foo;
}
if (year_time === 2024) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'X'+ this.foo;
}
if (year_time === 2025) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'Y'+ this.foo;
}
if (year_time === 2026) {
  lotNumber = lotNumber + 'Z'+ this.foo;
}

        lotNumber += result;
        this.lotService.saveLotNumber(sku, lotNumber).subscribe(res => {
          if (res && res.sku == sku) {
            this.lot_number = lotNumber + 'W';
            this.loadLastLot(sku);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
 <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip color="accent" selected (click)="generate()" > Generate New Lot #</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: Is this code you posted related to the question? If I'm understanding you correctly, you want there to be a pop-up prompt before (generate) is ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Angular and Angular Material for this you can use a [Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) to pop up when you click on the button and return the value of the input and check against your secret.

Even though the input does not display the password as you type remember that the data is being 'saved' as a string and is not encrypted in any way.

Click [here](https://angular-so-popup-example.stackblitz.io) to see my working example on Stackblitz.

HTML for the dialog:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>WARNING!</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>You are about to generate a new Lot #. YOU CAN'T UNDO IT</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="password" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

TS for Dialog:

```
export class SimpleDialogComponent {
  password = '';

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SimpleDialogComponent>) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

TS for AppComponent:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  // secret to validate the password
  secret = 'YESRUNFUNCTION';

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  generate(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SimpleDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(password => {
      const isPwdValid = password === this.secret;
      console.log(isPwdValid);
      if (isPwdValid) {
        // run code for correct password 
      } else {
        // run code for wrong password
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Dauglas. Im working on it but having a small issue: I can not include  two constructor  in one class it gives me an error :  constructor(private lotService: LotService) { } constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

Comment: Hello Markus, you should have only 1 constructor but pass 2 parameters like this: constructor(private lotService: LotService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modal (pop-up) to do this

[Here](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/7Ve8jy) is an example of how this might work:

In your html:

```
<modal id="custom-modal-1">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h1>A Custom Modal!</h1>
            <p>
                Enter the password: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="passwordText" />
            </p>
            <button (click)="generate();">Run generate function</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>
```

Then, in your typescript, declare your variable that is tied to the ngModel. The variable tied to the ngModel (passwordText) will be exactly the same as whatever the user is entering the in modal password prompt.

```
  private passwordText: any;

  generate() {
    // prevent function from running if password is incorrect
    if (this.passwordText !== 'some password') {
      return;
    }
   // your current code goes here
  }
```

And the CSS for the modal to be created, taken from the link:

```
/* MODAL STYLES
-------------------------------*/
modal {
    /* modals are hidden by default */
    display: none;

    .modal {
        /* modal container fixed across whole screen */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;

        /* z-index must be higher than .modal-background */
        z-index: 1000;

        /* enables scrolling for tall modals */
        overflow: auto;

        .modal-body {
            padding: 20px;
            background: #fff;

            /* margin exposes part of the modal background */
            margin: 40px;
        }
    }

    .modal-background {
        /* modal background fixed across whole screen */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;

        /* semi-transparent black  */
        background-color: #000;
        opacity: 0.75;

        /* z-index must be below .modal and above everything else  */
        z-index: 900;
    }
}

body.modal-open {
    /* body overflow is hidden to hide main scrollbar when modal window is open */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Credit to Jason Watmore for the modal example plnkr.